# CSS Gradient with calc()?

Tags: css, linear-gradients, calc

I'm trying to arrange some CSS to use for template files on a website. The template allows fixed colors to be specified for certain elements, like buttons or div elements.  What I'd like to do is replace the background color of certain elements like buttons with a gradient effect, however I want to preserve the functionality to use the template default color settings, in case someone else wants to use my template with different colors.

The code right now looks something like:

```
background: {template=bgcolor1};
```

where the bracketed area will be replaced by the template's defined color value, which can be RGB/RGBa/color names/hex value.

What I'd like be able to do is something like:

```
background: linear-gradient({template=bgcolor1}, calc({template=bgcolor1}+#101010));
```

or something to that effect.
Is there any CSS only method to accomplish something like this?

Comment: CSS can't do such color additions.

Comment: Look into [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) to accomplish this. Calc() does not work like that in CSS.

Comment: calc is an experimental tech in css, so support is sketchy https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc, also you cant use variables in css so use LESS or SASS as mentioned in above comment